# Snap pour points not recognizing sample sites as valid points when using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, arcgis-10.6

I am trying to go from a CSV of sample sites and a DEM to creating watersheds. I can process the DEM fine to stream networks and can import the points (first to event layer, then convert them to a feature class. The problem arises when I try to snap pour points (my sample sites) on to my flow accumulation raster to create the watersheds, the same error of "Sample_Sites do not exist" keeps popping up even though I can go to ArcMap and open them.

Any ideas on how to get around this problem?